# reactjs - class parent component call function child component method

Tags: reactjs

How do I use a parent(class component) to call a method in child(function component)?

This is what I have:

```
///child component(function)

function Child(props) {
const handleParent = () => { console.log("handling parent call")} ///<-- I want to call thuis.

return(
...
)
}

export default class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      consoletext:"",
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
  ...
 }

render(){
   return(
    <div>
      <Child />
    </div>
)
}
}
```

I try to use `useRef` in parent, but got an error:

> cannot use "useRef" in class component.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: First of all, it is a bad idea to mix functional components and class components. It will work as expected, but the code stinks. Also, can you be more specific on the purpose of this? I think there might be a better way to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: One way you can do it, is defining `handleParent` in the **`Parent`** component, and prop-drill that function to the child: `Parent` returns `<Child handler={handleParent} />`. Or you use React Context to make `handleParent` a somewhat global function both Parent and Child can access and use (which is usually overkill). Another side note is, for class-based component, `React.createRef()` is used (`useRef` is a React hook and thus is only used in functional components)

Answer (score 0):

`useRef` is a react hook that can only be used inside the functional component.

You can use [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) to customize the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using `ref`.

E.g.

`Parent.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  childRef;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.childRef = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.childRef && this.childRef.current) {
      this.childRef.current.handleParent();
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child ref={this.childRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`Child.tsx`:

```
import React, { useImperativeHandle } from "react";

const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const handleParent = () => {
    console.log("handling parent call");
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    handleParent
  }));

  return <div>child</div>;
});

export default Child;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-germain-sz7wi?file=/src/Child.tsx:0-295)